# Is the word order in "I am going on a holiday to Italy with my friend this week" correct?

Tags: word-order

Is the word order in this sentence correct?

> I am going on a holiday to Italy with my friend this week.

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U. Which words do you think might be out of order?

Comment: in this sentence, just about any word order would be correct, although each would have  slightly different emphasis. for example, "This week, I am going on a holiday..." would emphasize the time over other parts of the statement.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is correct.

You could also play around with the word order and it would still be right. e.g.

> This week I am going on a holiday to Italy with my friend.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer! Isn't the suggested word order now placing emphasis on the time?

Comment: I think it does very slightly (in speech you could choose how much emphasis) but @Scotland141 comment does have the advantage of breaking up the long list of qualifications of the word holiday: this week, to Italy, with my friend.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful comment @JeremyC. The number of qualifications was precisely why I wasn't quite sure about the right word order.